# C Array Bounds error with adjacent object

Tags: c

From http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/teaching/projects/Distinguished03/AndrewSuffield.pdf:

```
#include <string.h>

struct x
{
  char s[10];
  int a[4];
};

void bang(struct x *d)
{
  strcat(d->s, "!");
}

int main(void)
{
  struct x d;
  strcpy(d.s, "012345678");
  d.a[0] = 3;
  d.a[1] = 2;
  d.a[2] = 1;
  d.a[3] = 0;
  bang(&d);
  return a[0];
}
```

> In this example, struct x contains a 10-byte string immediately followed by a 4-integer array. d is initialized with a 9-character string (occupying 10 bytes because of the trailing NULL) and four integers. bang() appends a ! to the string, making it "012345678!" plus a trailing NULL.
>
> The NULL byte at the end of the string will overwrite the ﬁrst byte of d.a[0]. On a
>   big-endian host, this will have no effect because that byte was already zero. On a little-endian host, this will change the value of d.a[0] to zero

Two questions:

1. Will there not be structure holes present between s & a and so the above argument does not hold. gcc gives return vaue as 3.
2. return a[0] does not work on my system (gcc).

Comment: If you wish to play this example as it is intended, use the directives at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html to force GCC to omit the padding between the `.s` and `.a` fields.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour, so literally anything could happen.

Comment: @KerrekSB is there more UB than just using `d.s` before initialising it (or is that not a problem because `s` is an array)?

Comment: You're never "using `d.s` before initializing it", since you're not *reading* from it before writing to it. The `strcat` causes undefined behaviour, though, as it writes beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Actually no UB is invoked. The entire object is accessible via `char *` due to the *Representation of Types* in C. The only issue is the implementation-defined padding.

Comment: @R..: I think you're right about the lack of UB -- but it's still a Bad Thing To Do.

Comment: The use of the word "NULL" is misleading.  `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant; it should not be used to refer to the null character.  Yes, some character set standards, including Unicode, do refer to the null character as "NULL", but in the context of C "NULL" is a pointer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There could very well be padding between the fields. On any modern system there will be. Try passing `strcat` a longer string.
2. `return a[0]` is clearly a typo. It should read `return d.a[0]`.

Comment: The standard *permits* padding.  It only *requires* padding when it's necessary for proper alignment.  Possibly the example was written with 16-bit systems in mind; if `int` is only two bytes, then no alignment padding will be necessary.  (And if `int` is 4 bytes but only requires 2-byte alignment, again, no padding will be necessary.)

Comment: @keith I think I said nothing that contradicts that.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you did. Incidentally, I just took a look at the referenced pdf; it talks about modifying gcc, which as far as I know always makes `int` 32 bits.  Obviously the authors didn't bother to try their example (since it doesn't even compile).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, there probably will be padding between `s` and `a` to align `a` with `int` alignment.
2. You need to change it to `return d.a[0];`, there is no variable named just `a`.

Also realise that the bytes of `d.s` are not guaranteed to be initialised to `0` when you create it, and using it is undefined behaviour. So `strcat` could search for a NUL terminator and not find one and go into memory you don't own and cause a segfault. You should make `d.s` a C-string first before using `strcat`,

like this:

```
struct x d;
d.s[0] = 0;
```